# can I pass headers to redirected location after redirection?

Tags: redirect, cookies

here's response header of my redirection endpoint with status code 302.

```
"Location": "http://<target-domain>",
"Set-Cookie": "username=user1;"
```

I can see it redirects correctly to 302. but the cookie does not get set on the `<target-domain>`

Looks like the header `"Set-Cookie": "username=user1;"` does not get passed to the `<target-domain>` on redirection.

I see 2 network activities in my development tool,

1. redirection endpoint responds with status code 302. I see `Location` and `Set-Cookie` in the response header.
2. target domain responds with status code 200. I don't see `Location` and `Set-Cookie` anymore.

Is there a way to set the cookies on the `<target-domain>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set cookies on a domain other than the one you're on, so basically no. The only exception to this is you can set cookies on `example.com` if your current domain is something like `subdomain.example.com`, where you can attach the cookies to a shorter form of your domain, but it must be the same base domain.

If you need the other site to set a cookie with a value it does not know, you'll have to pass that value through somehow. Using a redirect with a query string leaves it open to tampering by the user unless you cryptographically sign it (annoying) or ship over a token that can be used to retrieve the raw value. You may need a short-term store for this, like Redis, Memcached, or even a database row you can purge later.

If it were possible to set cookies on any domain at all there'd be utter chaos. These things are heavily restricted for a reason.